# Is it possible to add multiple members in gitlab project simultaneously?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I need to add members to a gitlab project using gitlab API. I've successfully added members to the project using this format:

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" --data "user_id=1&access_level=30" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/:id/members
```

But I can only add a member one at a time. Is there any way I can add multiple members simultaneously?

Comment: What's stopping you from scripting this call in a loop?

Comment: I'm trying to lessen external API calls as much as possible

Answer (score 0):

You can add more than one user (for a given access level) to a project [through the Web GUI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/members/#add-a-user)

But the [project member API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/members/#add-a-user) does not seem to allow the same indeed.

An issue like [gitlab-org/gitlab-foss 31779](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/31779) has been rejected.
Same for [28681](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/28681) which remains unaddressed.